# Create small datasource with only 3 items

Tags: vb.net, webforms, devexpress

I was handed a legacy app built a few years back in VB.Net. I am modifying a DevExpress ASPxRadioButtonList and would like to use a small list of only 3 items that will never change as the datasource. It would be great if I could do the ds in the webform. It will basically be a list of "option 1", "option 2" or "both options". I dont need an SqlDataSource because there is no db call, these can be hard coded. What would be the best object to create that can be used as a datasource, and how would I manually add the 3 items to it in the webform? Most examples of things only show how to add items from the code behind.
Thanx so much in advance, I have learned so much from this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ITEMS property to add static items. Maybe utilize their online help or search using google

```
<dx:ASPxRadioButtonList ID="ASPxRadioButtonList1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0">
    <Items>
        <dx:ListEditItem Selected="True" Text="Option1" Value="Option1" />
        <dx:ListEditItem Text="Option2" Value="Option2" />
        <dx:ListEditItem Text="Both" Value="Both" />
    </Items>
</dx:ASPxRadioButtonList>
```

Comment: thanx so much, apparently I was over-thinking it.